# How to filter a scorecard using the MDX filter expression programmatically?

Tags: ssas, mdx, performancepoint

I have a scorecard which I would like to filter the data using MDX filter expressions.
I have got the MDX filter expression which consists of a filter applied on 2 columns, but I am just missing the last step of applying that filter on the scorecard, and getting the GridViewData.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag&drop the Member Unique Name after hovering over the filter name in the Dashboard editor pane and drop it to the Report you want to use with. In the window popping up check if it's trying to relate to the correct attribute and if so just hit OK and it should work.

Comment: The question was how to do so **Programmatically**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it in KPI. 
Hope the image below answers your question.

[image]